# Linking From Android App to Facebook Event

Tags: android, facebook

I have an android app from which I want to link to a Facebook event. Currently, I'm using fb://event/XXX (XXX is the event Facebook id) if the Facebook app is present, and https://www.facebook.com/XXX otherwise. Both of these only work some of the times, but most of the times what happens is that the Facebook app / page opens up and shows the feed, instead of the event page - as if it was opened regularly.

I should note that I have a version of the same app for iOS, there I use fb://profile/XXX / the https://www.facebook.com/XXX url and it works perfectly every time. Tried fb://profile in android, and it doesn't work.

Anyone successfully faced this issue?

Answer (score 0):

on Android it will work only if you have the app workin' and logged in...